# How to add an object inside an array inside an object in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to insert a task with multiple fields like title, text, and tag only in the 'To Do' category. It would be an object inside an array, inside an object. The way I'm implementing it is totally wrong, and it's generating a chain of objects inside another object. How could I be performing so that the data looks the same as in the Table?

This is the way I need the data to be saved:

```
const Table = [
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    title: "To do",
    tasks: [
      {
        id: uuidv4(),
        title: "Learn JavaScript",
        text: "lorem ipsum",
        tag: "tag1",
      },
      {
        id: uuidv4(),
        title: "Learn Git",
        text: "lorem ipsum",
        tag: "tag2",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    title: "Doing",
    tasks: [
      {
        id: uuidv4(),
        title: "Learn CSS",
        text: "lorem ipsum",
        tag: "tag1",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    title: "Done",
    tasks: [
      {
        id: uuidv4(),
        title: "Learn HTML",
        text: "lorem ipsum",
        tag: "tag1",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

This is the code I made

```
  import React, { useState } from "react";
import Input from "./Input";
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
  function addTask(task) {
    const newTask = { ...task };
    newTask[0] = {
      ...tasks[0],
      arrayTasks: task,
    };
    setTasks([...tasks, newTask]);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Input onAdd={addTask} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

and this one:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Input = ({ onAdd }) => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [tag, setTag] = useState("");
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("ToDo");

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!text || !title) {
      alert("Please enter a task with a title");
      return;
    }
    const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1;
    const id = "" + number;
    onAdd({ title, text, tag, status, id });
    setTitle("");
    setText("");
    setTag("");
    setStatus("ToDo");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Add Title"
        value={title}
        onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Add Task"
        value={text}
        onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Insert you tag"
        value={tag}
        onChange={(e) => setTag(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit}>
        Save Task
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5t0Pu.png)

Comment: You haven't provided enough code to reproduce your example. What is the type of `task`, why would you `await { ...task }`, why are you creating `newTask` from `task` and then assigning `newTasks[0]` `{ ...tasks[0], arrayTasks: task }`. This seems immensely redundant. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: I'd simply use three state arrays for this. There's no need for a more complicated structure here.

Comment: Anyway, you're looking for this I guess: https://jsfiddle.net/wcfdk6pe/

Comment: I'll try to adapt it in my code, but that's exactly what I needed, thanks! ChrisG. I had put it with await because I'm using local storage.

Answer (score 0):

if you expect your task state to be like the table array.
so i think you need first to refer to which item in the array to update.
so i suggest you need to pass an extra param to the function `'id of the target item or row'`.

and so, you can try something like this.

```
// the second param is the id of target row or item which contain the tasks obj.

    // 1. take an instance of the original array
    // 2. get the index of the object you want to update
    // 3. return the rest of the array without the target object we need to update.
    // 4. access the target object we need to update
    // 5. add your tasks to the target object
    // 6. return the rest of the array with the updated object.

function addTask(task, id) {
    const tasksCopy = [...tasks]; // should be a copy of table variable

    const targetObjIndex = tasksCopy.findIndex((tbl) => tbl.id === id);
    const resetOfTheArray = tasksCopy.filter((tbl) => tbl.id !== id);

    let targetItem = tasksCopy[targetObjIndex];

    targetItem = { ...targetItem, tasks: [...targetItem.tasks, task] };

  return [...resetOfTheArray, targetItem];
}
```